# Does java string.trim also trim "\n" as well

Tags: java, string, trim

I was testing the java `trim` method

Test Code:

```
 public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String t = "testcode\n";        
        System.out.print(t.trim() + "**");              
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
testcode**
```

The documentation says:

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing white-space omitted

But as we can see it also removed "\n"

*Is this the expected behavior and documentation is misleading ?*

ENVIRONMENT: oracle java7

Comment: yes it trims new lines also as you have observed- no i dont think it is misleading because new lines are whitespace and trim() gets rid of whitespace

Comment: Last time I checked, \n was [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character), too, wasn't it?

Comment: read the full documentation for the method, not just the first line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, \n is considered whitespace, so the trim() method would remove it along with any other trailing space in the String.